# Is it possible to create modal JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering if it would be possible to use a JPopupMenu as modal, let's say, such as for example a fileChooser..

```
int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(EC_GUI.main);

if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
```

I tried to google it, but I did not find anything

Comment: what do you mean by `modal`?

Comment: I mean that the code stops and waits for any action coming from the user, somelike JPopupMenu.OPTION1, JPopupMenu.OPTION2 or JPopupMenu.NOTHING

Comment: I would say you need usual JDialog with list/table of options

Comment: use popupmenulistener? is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I second the call for `JDialog`